# Read XML on SQL Server : Select custom attribute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, readxml

I'm trying to read an XML, it works pretty well on the whole except for the attribute named :

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="loyaltyNumber">1234567890</custom-attribute>
```

which I am trying to get the value "1234567890"

Here is the test code:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<customers>
<customer customer-no="00000001">
        <credentials>
            <login>test@email.com</login>
        </credentials>
        <profile>
            <preferred-locale>fr_BE</preferred-locale>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="ServiceId">1</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="loyaltyNumber">1234567890</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </profile>
        <note/>
    </customer>
    <customer customer-no="00000002">
        <credentials>
            <login>test2@email.com</login>
        </credentials>
        <profile>
            <preferred-locale>fr_FR</preferred-locale>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="loyaltyNumber">1234567890</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </profile>
        <note/>
    </customer>
</customers>'
 
SELECT
    CustomerNo = Events.value('@customer-no', 'int'),
    --EventType = Events.value('@Type', 'varchar(20)'),
    CustomerLogin =Events.value('(credentials/login)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
    CustomerLocal =Events.value('(profile/preferred-locale)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
    EventKind =Events.value('(profile/custom-attributes/custom-attribute)[2]', 'varchar(60)')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/customers/customer') AS XTbl(Events)
```

The current result is:

| CustomerNo | CustomerLogin | CustomerLocal | EventKind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test@email.com | fr_BE | 1234567890 |
| 2 | test2@email.com | fr_FR | NULL |

And it's logical since custom-attributes are optional, so you can't access them with the index.
So I'm looking for a way to access them by name: attribute-id="loyaltyNumber"

Thanks,

Comment: You should add `/text()` after each XQuery to get the inner text of the node, otherwise it can be slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..filter the path to the attribute which has attribute-id = “loyaltyNumber”

```
EventKind =Events.value('(profile/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="loyaltyNumber"])[1]', 'varchar(60)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the attribute-id of the custom attribute to your query:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<customers>
<customer customer-no="00000001">
        <credentials>
            <login>test@email.com</login>
        </credentials>
        <profile>
            <preferred-locale>fr_BE</preferred-locale>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="ServiceId">1</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="loyaltyNumber">1234567890</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </profile>
        <note/>
    </customer>
    <customer customer-no="00000002">
        <credentials>
            <login>test2@email.com</login>
        </credentials>
        <profile>
            <preferred-locale>fr_FR</preferred-locale>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="loyaltyNumber">1234567777</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </profile>
        <note/>
    </customer>
</customers>'
 
SELECT
    CustomerNo = Events.value('@customer-no', 'int'),
    --EventType = Events.value('@Type', 'varchar(20)'),
    CustomerLogin =Events.value('(credentials/login)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
    CustomerLocal =Events.value('(profile/preferred-locale)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
    EventKind =Events.value('(profile/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id = "loyaltyNumber"])[1]', 'varchar(60)')
FROM
 @XML.nodes('/customers/customer') AS XTbl(Events)
```